# FlutterError (setState() called after dispose(): _StartPageState#13a2d(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)

Tags: flutter, dart

i try to check the user authenticity first...if authenticated...i display `Home(passedSelectedIndex: 0)` if not i display `StartPage()`

here is my code:

```
class HomeController extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeControllerState createState() => _HomeControllerState();
}

bool isAuthenticated = false;

class _HomeControllerState extends State<HomeController> {
  AuthService authService = locator.get<AuthService>();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkAuthenticity();
  }

   checkAuthenticity() {
    authService.getCurrentUser().then((user) async {
      if (user != null) {
        String myUid = await authService.getCurrentUID();
        await MyUserController().getCurrentUserFromFirebase(myUid);
        if (mounted)
          setState(() {
            isAuthenticated = true;
          });
      } else {
        if (mounted)
          setState(() {
            isAuthenticated = false;
          });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: isAuthenticated ? Home(passedSelectedIndex: 0) : StartPage(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

in the above code:

```
   checkAuthenticity() {
    authService.getCurrentUser().then((user) async {
      if (user != null) {
        String myUid = await authService.getCurrentUID();
        await MyUserController().getCurrentUserFromFirebase(myUid);
        if (mounted)
          setState(() {
            isAuthenticated = true;
          });
      } else {
        if (mounted)
          setState(() {
            isAuthenticated = false;
          });
      }
    });
  }
```

is working well and doing its job as intended...the problem is that everytime i `setState((){isAuthenticated = true})` and the screen should be changed to : `Home(passedSelectedIndex: 0)`
because now iam an authenticated user.

i get this error:

```
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (setState() called after dispose(): _StartPageState#13a2d(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
```

what is going wrong here?!

any help would be much appreciated.

many thanks

Comment: Do you navigate to the new page and when do you get the error? On loaded or when you want to navigate?

Comment: i edited the question...infact i am not willing to get navigated to any other screen...its just only one screen...make user see StartPage() if he is not authenticated....or proceed to home page Home(passedSelectedIndex: 0) if he is an authenticated user.

Comment: I don't get it, when do you get this error?

Comment: when this   setState(() {
            isAuthenticated = true;
          });  executes

Comment: What happens if you don't use SetState? Remove the if statement and the setstate

Comment: nothing will happen...i will be stuck in StartPage() whether iam an authenticated user or not....the main point here is that i check if am an authenticated user...if so...i setSetate((){isAuthenticated = true}) to re draw the UI..and after the redraw....in the MaterialApp widget's home...i make a bool check, if isAuthented ? Home(passedSelectedIndex: 0) : StartPage()

Comment: i suspected StartPage() itself that might contain a setState((){}) function and that was really the culprit....in StartPage() i have this      return Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 3000), () {
      setState(() {
        
      });
    });  as you see...it gets executed after 3 seconds...and before the 3 seconds pass...i wass redrawing the UI with another screen which is Home(passedSelectedIndex: 0)....after disabling this Future.delayed function...everythig works well.....thanks anyway :)